# MVC 4 Controller Functions Exception String reference not set to an instance of a String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building my first project in MVC 4 and Its related with Database. I am using only one Controller which have three Functions Insert,Delete and Update and using One Model but Multiply Views.
Whenever I Run the Website, its give me form which have three Buttons. Here's the Sample of those Buttons.

[image]

The Insert Button Run Correctly but When I click on Delete it gives me Exception in Controller String reference not set to an instance of a String.

Now, Here's my Piece of Code:

Controller:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult inserted(string user)
    {


            DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UserProperties));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(user));

            UserProperties userData = (UserProperties)js.ReadObject(ms);
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=A11_MVC;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("insertProcedure", sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Age", userData.Age));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Email", userData.Email));

            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
            }

            sqlConnection.Close();
            RedirectToAction("showAll");
            return View();  
    }


    //------------------------------------------- *DELETE* ------------------------------------//
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Delete(string user)
    {


        DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UserProperties));

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(user));
        UserProperties userData = (UserProperties)js.ReadObject(ms);
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=A11_MVC;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("deleteProcedure", sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", userData.ID));


        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
        }
        sqlConnection.Close();
        RedirectToAction("showAll");
        return View();


    }
```

And Here's the Exception Image:

[image]

What is the Mistake that I am Doing? And sorry about my English.

Comment: It would help if you also added a snippet from your .cshtml (I presume) file for the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user parameter in the controller is null. That's the problem. Check the generated URL. It does come with the user string?

Comment: How can I detect that the URL is generating the request etc? I am Using this:@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete");

Comment: You can pass extra parameters with Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "YourController", new { user = value_from_model }, null)